# FormatException during Json.net deserialization

Tags: c#, xamarin, serialization, json.net

I'm faced wiht an error, and I don't know how to correct it. I don't understand why it comes.

> System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

The exception comes when I try to deserialize a JSON into objects that I created. (The second line code is throwing the exception)

```
List<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject2>(content);
connections = root.connections;
```

Here is the JSON that I want to use:

http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/connections?from=lausanne&to=fribourg

And here are my objects:

```
public class RootObject2
{
    public List<Connection> connections { get; set; }
}

 public class Connection
    {
        public Stop from { get; set; }
        public Stop to { get; set; }
        public string duration { get; set; }
        public int? transfers { get; set; }
        public Service service { get; set; }
        public List<string> products { get; set; }
        public int? capacity1st { get; set; }
        public int? capacity2nd { get; set; }
        public List<Section> sections { get; set; }
    }

  public class Stop
    {
        public Station station { get; set; }
        public DateTime arrival { get; set; }
        public int? arrivalTimestamp { get; set; }
        public string departure { get; set; }
        public int? departureTimestamp { get; set; }
        public int? delay { get; set; }
        public string platform { get; set; }
        public Prognosis prognosis { get; set; }
        public string realtimeAvailability {get; set;}
        public Station location { get; set; }
    }

   public class Station
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int? score { get; set; }
        public Coordinate coordinate { get; set; }
        public double? distance { get; set; }
    }

   public class Service
    {
        public string regular { get; set; }
        public string irregular { get; set; }
    }

   public class Section
    {
        public Journey journey { get; set; }
        public Walk walk { get; set; }
        public Stop departure { get; set; }
        public Stop arrival { get; set; }
    }


   public class Journey
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string category { get; set; }
            public string subcategory { get; set; }
            public int? categoryCode { get; set; }
            public string number { get; set; }
            public string @operator { get; set; }
            public string to { get; set; }
            public List<Stop> passList { get; set; }
            public int? capacity1st { get; set; }
            public int? capacity2nd { get; set; }
        }


 public class Walk
    {
        public string duration { get; set; }
    }

public class Prognosis
{
    public string platform { get; set; }
    public string arrival { get; set; }
    public string departure { get; set; }
    public int? capacity1st { get; set; }
    public int? capacity2nd { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinate
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization is on a try and catch block, and nothing is catched.
Also I am doing this on Android.

Comment: `connections = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Connection>>(json);`: Why are you not deserializing to the `RootObject2`, in this case?

Comment: @EBrown it's a mistake, I just edited my answer. I have this like you mentionned, I was just trying different possibilites.

Comment: It seems like you need to edit your answer again.

Comment: It is correct now

Comment: I imitated what you did, and I received this error: http://imgur.com/a/u1Zsa with `var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject2>(content);`

Comment: "The deserialization is on a try and catch block, and nothing is catched." - I'm confused. You've said that the exception is on your deserialize but then you say that nothing is caught (which means either you are not catching the right exceptions or that in fact nothing is being thrown. Could you clarify why you are sure that it is the call to Deserialize that is causing this problem? For what its worth a stack trace would probably help too to understand fully what is happening.

Comment: As an added thought are you sure that you aren't throwing an exception in your catch block or something which would explain why its seemingly not catching the exception?

Comment: I know because when I debug, nothing happens until this line reaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on json data.

- `Arrival` property in Stop class should be `DateTime?`.

Comment: I vouch this fixes the problem! :)

Comment: It has indeed resolved my problem :O. Why is the "?" after the property for?

Comment: It's just syntax sugar for `Nullable<DateTime>`.

Comment: The `?` says that it is of type `Nullable<DateTime>` rather than DateTime. Nullable types are used for value types which can't normally be null when you need null to be a valid option. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx for more info

Comment: Thank you all, I can now continue developing my project :D